# Can an Amazon RDS SQL Server link to an RDS MySQL server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, amazon-rds, linked-server

Amazon RDS for SQL Server supports linked servers, but the [doc page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-linked-servers-with-amazon-rds-for-microsoft-sql-server/) only describes linking to other SQL Servers.  I would like to link to an RDS MySQL instance, but this normally involves installing the relevant ODBC driver and/or creating a DSN - and I believe both are impossible on RDS.

Is there any way to create a linked server on an RDS SQL Server, which points to an RDS MySQL server?  I'll be a little surprised if this is really not available; presumably a fix would work for Aurora as well as MySQL, and encourage adoption of Amazon's preferred platform.

Comment: While it's possible a peer here has done this (or tried and failed), your best bet is the RDS support team.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: agreed, and if they give an answer I'll record it here for posterity.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades did you get this figured out?

Comment: @HannahVernon no, sorry.  I don't recall what Amazon support said, but I'm 99% confident it was unhelpful or I would have remembered to record it here.